# Fatest algorithm to generate many distinct random undirected graphs with multiple edges given number of nodes and node degree

Tags: python, graph

I wrote an algorithm that generates random graphs given number of nodes and associated node degree. The algorithm is slow for large graphs. It works like this:

1. Pick 2 random nodes from node list and connect them while checking node degree of these nodes hasn't reached capacity. Also every random graph must be different from previous ones given this is possible (1000 graphs)

Sometimes algorithm reaches an exception as I randomly pick nodes to connect, and in the end I am left with a node with a large unassigned degree. And since I cannot have self loops, I start breaking random edges from intermediate graph and connecting them to this node. I think this is naive and inefficient. Any guidance on how to go about this?
Graph is undirected with no self loops but multiple edges between 2 nodes.
Tried using python libraries that do this like configuration model but they allow self loops

```
for iteration in range(1000):  # 1000 random graphs
    all_stop = False
    all_stop_2 = False
    count = count +1
    
    success_dict = defaultdict(list)  
    popped_dict = defaultdict(dict)
    grid_dens_dict = defaultdict(set)
        
    with open(filename2,'rb') as handle:
        pfxlinks = pickle.load(handle,encoding ='latin-1')  


    with open(filename3,'rb') as handle:
        grid_ids_withlinks = pickle.load(handle,encoding ='latin-1')
    
    for pfxpair in pfxlinks:
        start_put = False    
        end_put = False 
        
        if all_stop_2 == True:
            break
        
        while True:
            
            if all_stop == True:
                all_stop_2 = True
                break
           
            try:
                grid_start_id, grid_end_id = (np.random.choice(list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys()),size = 2, replace = False)) # get 2 random node ids
                grid_start_id = int(grid_start_id)
                grid_end_id = int(grid_end_id)
                
                if start_put == False:
                    
                    start_value = grid_dens_dict.get(grid_start_id)    # if node id exists in my dict and node degree hasnt reached capacity
                    
                    start_process_condition = (not start_value) or ( (start_value) and (len(grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id]) < grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id]) )
                    if start_process_condition:
                        grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id].add(pfxpair)
                        start_put = True
                    
                        if len(grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id]) == grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id]: # node degree for node full, remove from dict
                            
                            try:
                                #print('deleted key: ',grid_start_id, 'with size:',grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id],'Capacity:',grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id])
                                popped_dict[grid_start_id] = {'orig_capacity': grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id],'size':len(grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id]) }
        
                                grid_ids_withlinks.pop(grid_start_id)
                            
                            except:
                                print('already popped')
                else:
                    print('check')
                              
                if end_put == False: 
                    
                                        
                    end_value = grid_dens_dict.get(grid_end_id)
                    if (not end_value) or (end_value and (len(grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id]) < grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id])):
                        grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id].add(pfxpair)
                        end_put = True
                        
                        if len(grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id]) == grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id]:
                            try:
                                #print('deleted key: ',grid_end_id, 'with size:',grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id],'Capacity:',grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id])
                                popped_dict[grid_end_id] = {'orig_capacity': grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id],'size':len(grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id]) }
        
                                grid_ids_withlinks.pop(grid_end_id)
        
                            except:
                                print('already popped')
                else:
                    print('check')
                
                if (start_put == False and end_put == True):      # only end while when both nodes have been assigned a link
                    grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id].discard(pfxpair)
                    end_put = False
                if (start_put == True and end_put == False):
                    grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id].discard(pfxpair)
                    start_put = False
        
                        
                if start_put == True and end_put == True:
                    success_dict[pfxpair].append((grid_start_id,grid_end_id))
        
                    break
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve for the graph with maximum edge weight subject to degree constraints using linear programming. In general, choosing different random weights will lead to different graphs. Here is an example using PuLP:

```
# !pip install PuLP
import pulp
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

# set up fake data
np.random.seed(0)
num_nodes = 10
node_list = list(range(num_nodes))
degrees = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=num_nodes)

# random weights, num_nodes by num_nodes
rw = np.random.rand(num_nodes, num_nodes)

# define optimization problem
lp_problem = pulp.LpProblem(name="RandomGraph")

# define optimization variables
edges = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Edges", (node_list, node_list), cat="Binary")

# objective is to find the matching with maximum random edge weights
lp_problem += sum(edges[i][j] * rw[i,j]
            for i in node_list for j in node_list)

# graph is undirected:
for i, j in combinations(node_list, 2):
  lp_problem += edges[i][j] == edges[j][i]

# no self-loops:
for i in node_list:
  lp_problem += edges[i][i] == 0

# degree constraints are respected:
for i in node_list:
  lp_problem += sum(edges[i][j] for j in node_list) == degrees[i]

# solve the problem
lp_problem.solve()
# make sure that we got an optimal solution
assert lp_problem.status == 1
# recover edges
edges_solution = [(i, j) for i in node_list for j in node_list
                   if edges[i][j].varValue == 1]

# visualize the graph
import networkx as nx

# construct networkx graph
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from(edges_solution)
for i, d in enumerate(degrees):
  g.nodes[i]["intended_degree"] = d

# draw, labeling the intended degrees
labels = nx.get_node_attributes(g, 'intended_degree')
nx.draw_circular(g, labels=labels)
```

The following picture shows that node degrees are correct:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I never knoew about this approach. Can I generate a 1000 different random graphs using this approach? Ofcourse if node and node degree variation allow for such 1000 graphs. Also is using weight s the only reason that gives us different graphs while maintaing node degree? Does this bias the generated graph in any way as probability of choosing an edge is preset? I need to use this for a statistical test and hence must be random

Comment: For `degrees = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=40)`, generating 1000 random graphs produces 977 unique values, so generating 1000 graphs should be feasible with some bookkeeping. I am not sure what the resulting distribution is. If you are looking for a uniform distribution on valid graphs, you might want to ask on math.stackexchange as well.

Comment: I forgot to mention that we start with a original graph with a given no of nodes and node degree per node. This is my starting point and i would generate 1000 random graph while maintaing total nodes and node degree per node. Does this method still work?

Comment: Yes, you can generate many random graphs with the same node list and node degrees using this method (`degrees` stays fixed while random weights `rw` change across different optimization calls).

Comment: Hi. Tried above solution for a case with total_nodes =93, node_degree_list = [751065,15256,108969,17038,6749,6476,107431,45946,3594,10860,2126,52518,21211,94587,43891,17073,999,4347,2072,119736,3284,2404,3815,16598,4514,310,4265,5468,2176,2067,19090,8454,3041,4159,2204,9732,2041,2167,17056,34769,2025,2176,1886,988,6818,12509,6186,4272,3,39,294,27,21,10766,3523,53,2199,4347,3029,238,4070,2065,1590,4345,2131,4053,19,2124,11,8,158,112,112,6245,155,6315,3978,2234,2032,2672,13,52,20,2,56,6,11,23,6,12,10,25,6]. assert lp_problem.status == 1 shows error. Edge solution contains only 92 nodes